# Problem with bash scripting

Tags: bash

I'm terrible with bash scripting, and need some help with the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -e Pretty* ];then
ncftpput -R -DD -v -u xbmc -p xbmc 192.168.1.100 /home/xbmc/TV/Pretty_Little_Liars/ Pretty*
else
echo "No new folders"
fi

find -depth -type d -empty -exec rmdir {} \;
```

Problem here is the ncftpput line.. if I just do a simple [ echo "working" ] instead, everything is OK, but when I try the ncftpput-line it just gives me [ line 5: [: too many arguments
 ]

the ncftpput command alone works fine..

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm pretty sure "how to copy around my pirated TV" is off topic for this site. Not on moral grounds or anything; it's just out of scope.

Comment: It's actually "how to copy new recordings from my networked pvrbox to my media center" ;)

Comment: The assumption that everything is always illegal is tiresome. :( Aside from all else, not every has the same laws.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use globbing with `-e` inside `[]` because it's likely to return more than one result which will give you a too many arguments error.

You can try:

```
shopt -s nullglob
if [[ -n "$(echo Pretty*)" ]]
```

or

```
if [[ "$(echo Pretty*)" != "Pretty*" ]]
```

Also, use indenting, spaces and line continuation to make your code more readable:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob
if [[ -n "$(echo Pretty*)" ]]; then
    ncftpput -R -DD -v -u xbmc -p xbmc 192.168.1.100 \
        /home/xbmc/TV/Pretty_Little_Liars/ Pretty*
else
    echo "No new folders"
fi

find -depth -type d -empty -exec rmdir {} \;
```

Comment: Thank you soo much! That was it :) And I learned something new today too!

Comment: This question was migrated due to it being just a scripting question. There are lots of other bash scripting questions that exist on Super User.

Comment: @Troggy: There are lots of scripting questions on SO. Perhaps they should be moved *en masse* and banned. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try it.

```
#!/bin/bash -x

if [ -e "Pretty*" ];then
`ncftpput -R -DD -v -u xbmc -p xbmc 192.168.1.100 /home/xbmc/TV/Pretty_Little_Liars/ Pretty*`
else
echo "No new folders"
fi

find -depth -type d -empty -exec rmdir {} \;
```

Comment: Thanks for trying, but that doesn't work :( When it is written like that the wildcard (*) doesn't match anything.

Comment: Weird... 
If I use "" in (if [ -e "Pretty*" ];then
it doesn't give me a "too many arguments" error, but * don't work as a wildcard..

Answer (score 0):

Well, if it's complaining of too many arguments, break it with a for.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -e Pretty* ];then
   for FILE in Pretty*
   do
       ncftpput -R -DD -v -u xbmc -p xbmc 192.168.1.100 /home/xbmc/TV/Pretty_Little_Liars/ "$FILE"
   done
else
   echo "No new folders"
fi

find -depth -type d -empty -exec rmdir {} \;
```

Using the "" around $FILE will ensure that files with spaces on their name don't do anything unexpected.

Comment: This one is also complaining about too many arguments.

If it matters: Pretty* is several folders with different names, all starting with "Pretty"

None of the folder have spaces in them..

Comment: Run the ncftpput line (with all your options) plus a folder name and see if it gives you the same error. I am not familiar with ncftpput but seems to be something wrong with that line.

Comment: The ncftpput line alone works just fine, no errors, and it's does what's expected.